# Extraer el array en componentes json , que parezcan arrays consecutivos

Tags: php, javascript, laravel-5, laravel-blade, c3.js

Me encuentro ante la disyuntiva siguiente:

Estoy usando la api C3.js de estadísticas en un proyecto , donde quiero hacer una gráfica de hora del día y los accesos a un edificio , tengo :

```
var chart4 = c3.generate({

    bindto: '#estadisticaTemporal',
    data: {
        x: 'Hora',
        xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00',
        columns:
            {!! $fechaAcceso['horas'] !!},
            {!! $fechaAcceso['acceso'] !!}
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            // if true, treat x value as localtime (Default)
            // if false, convert to UTC internally
            localtime: false,
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

El array esta formado por :

```
[
  "horas" => ["Hora" , "2017-09-06 10:00:00"]
  "acceso" => [["entradas" , "0"],["salidas,"1"]]
]
```

La cuestión que me los imprime de esta manera :

```
columns:
             ["Hora" , "2017-09-06 10:00:00"],
           [["entradas" , "0"],["salidas,"1"]]
    },
```

lo que yo quiero es :

```
columns:
             ["Hora" , "2017-09-06 10:00:00"],
           ["entradas" , "0"],["salidas","1"] // Como podéis ver es distinto
    },
```

Comment: en `data` pones que la segunda columna sea `acceso`. Si quieres 3 columnas ,no deberias poner que  coja el primer elemento de `acceso` (entradas) para la segunda columna y el segundo elemento de `acceso`(salidas) como tercera columna?

Comment: no , este coponente de C3 , en modo gráfica temporal , tienes que poner primero las fechas que son los ejes X y luego poner las intersecciones de los distintos para definir así las número de gráficas , en este caso sería el tiempo intersecado por dos Y , que serían el de entradas y salidas por tiempo.

Comment: Pero al final en la seccion de *"lo que quiero es"*  hay 3 columnas

Comment: una de ellas es la x y la otras son las y's , puedes ver mi respuesta abajo más detallada.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente lo que he echo después de darle vueltas , fue comprender que era un json , al final de cuentas es como si fuera un string para la variable PHP , por consiguiente he jugado con `strlen` para que me dijera la longitud y con `substr` para mejorar recortar por donde me interesaba.

```
$array = [
  ["entradas" , 0,2,3,2,31,32,32,23,2,1,4,1,5,1,2,3,4],
  ["salidas" , 1,2,3,44,2,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4],
];
$arrayJson = json_encode($array);
echo json_encode($array);
$arrayFormat = substr($arrayJson,1,strlen($arrayJson));
$arrayFormat = substr($arrayFormat,-strlen($arrayJson),-1);
echo $arrayFormat;
```

Salidas :

```
 // primer echo (aqui lo pongo formateado
 [
  ["entradas",0,2,3,2,31,32,32,23,2,1,4,1,5,1,2,3,4],
  ["salidas",1,2,3,44,2,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]
 ]
 // Segundo echo
 ["entradas",0,2,3,2,31,32,32,23,2,1,4,1,5,1,2,3,4],
 ["salidas",1,2,3,44,2,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]
```

Como resultado daría esto : 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis observar donde pone las fechas , son el eje de los X y los otros dos las dos gráficas superpuestas las Y.

Como aclaración :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar de `substr` mejor busca una librería que parsee JSON